# SQL 2008R2 Snapshot issue

Tags: sql-server, snapshot

I couldn't tell who is taking database snapshot of a MS SQL database. 
I've started trace looked at all the jobs but still couldn't tell who's taking the database snapshots. All i see in the error log is starting up the snapshot database.

Where should I be looking at? What kind of trace should I run?

Answer (score 0):

if you run a sp_helpdb 
on the snapshot database you should see who the owner is and that is the person who created the snapshot.

Comment: Yes I looked at it, it was created by a sa account even the application ppl aren't aware about it.

Comment: Could you try SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id)
FROM syscomments
WHERE text LIKE '%as snapshot of%' This will give you all scripts that are creating snapshots. Once you identify the scrips use profiler to monitor the script